# Logging the name of a tkinter Variable

Tags: python-3.x, logging, tkinter

I'm adding some logging function to my tkinter app. Ideally, the function will tell the name of the variable it changed and the value it's been changed to. Below is the relevant code.

This declares the instance variables that I'm using:

```
## priorityLevel
self.rbPriorityValue          = StringVar()
self.rbPriority               = None
self.rbMinor                  = None
```

This set the values of everything:

```
self.rbPriority = ttk.Radiobutton(cf, text="Priority", variable=self.rbPriorityValue, value="priority",
                                  command=lambda: self.rbValueChanged(self.rbPriorityValue, self.rbPriority))
self.rbPriority.grid(row=21, column=0, sticky="w", padx=(indent, 0))
self.rbMinor = ttk.Radiobutton(cf, text="Minor", variable=self.rbPriorityValue, value="minor",
                               command=lambda: self.rbValueChanged(self.rbPriorityValue, self.rbMinor))
self.rbMinor.grid(row=22, column=0, sticky="w", padx=(indent, 0))
```

This is the logging function:

```
def rbValueChanged(self, radioValue, modifiedWidget):
    print("The value of %s is:" % radioValue.__str__(), end="\t\t")
    print(modifiedWidget.cget("value"))
#end rbValueChanged
```

When I select the radio button the logging function prints "PY_VAR25" instead of "rbPriorityValue". Is there any way to return this, or is PY_VAR25 the best I can get?

Comment: The StringVar has no way of knowing what name you're using to refer to it.  You can pass a `name=` parameter when creating the var to override it's automatically-generated name, but note that it becomes entirely your responsibility to give each var a distinct name - accidentally duplicating a name will NOT produce any error message.

Comment: If StringVar doesn't, then shouldn't the object that the StringVar is a member of know?

Comment: You can probably use `trace` to listen to your variables and trigger logging.

Comment: What is trace, and how would I use it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name` kwarg on a tkinter [`Variable`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L308) class object.

```
a_variable = StringVar(name="variable A")
```

Here is a short example demonstrating its use to obtain a more readable log:

```
import tkinter as tk
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def button_press(var):
    log_entry = f'variable name: {var}, value: {var.get()}'
    logging.debug(log_entry)
    # print(log_entry)


root = tk.Tk()

a_variable = tk.StringVar(value='A', name="variable A")
tk.Button(text='press A', command=lambda var=a_variable: button_press(var)).pack()

b_variable = tk.StringVar(value='B', name="variable B")
tk.Button(text='press B', command=lambda var=b_variable: button_press(var)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**output:**

press A: `DEBUG:root:variable name: variable A, value: A`
press B: `DEBUG:root:variable name: variable B, value: B`